# Javascript to get the text of checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript

How can I get the checked checkboxes using JavaScript for the following HTML.
All my check boxes will have id's as follows as shown in the HTML

```
SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_0
SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_1
// ... and so on, up to
SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_n
```

I tried with the following code

```js
var IDtoFind="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_"
var txts = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < txts.length; ++i) {
  if (txts[i].name.indexOf(IDtoFind)!=-1) {
    if(txts[i].checked){ alert(txts[i].id); }
    // targetId = txts[i].id;
  }
}
```

But its not working . Ineed to get the text of the checkbox labels

```html
<table id="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <span class="ms-RadioText" title="NO SECURITY ISSUE Observed">
       <input id="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
       <label for="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_0">NO SECURITY ISSUE Observed</label>
      </span>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <span class="ms-RadioText" title="Staff NOT wearing  identification / name badge">
       <input id="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_1" type="checkbox">
       <label for="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_1">Staff NOT wearing  identification / name badge</label>
     </span>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Comment: You are checking the `.name` property, when the ID is stored in the `.id` property. You'll never find anything if you look in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the nextelementsibling property like

```js
function get() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id^="SECURITY_"]'),
    labels = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      labels.push(inputs[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML.trim())
    }
  }
  alert(labels)
}
```

```html
<table id="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="ms-RadioText" title="NO SECURITY ISSUE Observed">
          <input id="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
          <label for="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_0">NO SECURITY ISSUE Observed</label>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="ms-RadioText" title="Staff NOT wearing  identification / name badge">
          <input id="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_1" type="checkbox">
          <label for="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_1">Staff NOT wearing  identification / name badge</label>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="get()">Get</button>
```

---

Note: You can simplify the checkbox selector, if you can add a class to those checkboxes

```
<input id="SECURITY_6ab5ce28-f328-4096-91c1-db49a5007d0c_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="security-multichoiceoption"/>
```

then

```
inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('security-multichoiceoption')
```

Comment: Thanks Arun I will try your code as this one is auto generated HTML in SharePoint

Comment: @user3476088 note: it will work for IE>=9 only.... for IE 8+ http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ge37gLwy/2/

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://codepen.io/nikos_efthias/pen/xGexOY?editors=101)
i made a demo which returns an array of maching objects you can simply reach elements by using those function there it returns an array so `those()[0].id` will simply return the id of first selected element